Issue with Outdated File and Formatting in Form Notifications
Dear Google Forms Support Team,
I am experiencing a strange issue with the automatic response set up through Form Notifications for one of my forms.
I have included a Google Drive link in the notification email which customers get when I apply to a course via a forms document. When I test the link separately—by clicking it or entering it into the browser—it directs me to the correct, up-to-date document. However, when I complete a test registration for the form and receive the automatic confirmation email, it seems to link to an older version of the file. Additionally, the subject line of the email is distorted, containing random percentage signs, which do not exist in the original file or anywhere else in the system.
To clarify:

I verified that the Drive link in the form notification is correct, up to date, and properly shared with the necessary permissions.

In the file information/version history of the Google Drive document, the latest version is clearly uploaded and active. Despite this, the email pulls an outdated version of the document with strange characters (percentage signs) in the subject line. The original document only contains hyphens as special characters, with no other formatting issues.

The formatting issue (percent signs) only appears in the automated email notification.


I have double-checked everything and ensured the current Drive file is correct, but I still cannot figure out why the notification is displaying the old version of the document and why these formatting errors are appearing.
Could you please help me resolve this issue? I need to ensure that our course participants receive the correct document.
Thank you very much for your assistance!
Best regards,
